# How to combine several categorical variables into one quality of health measure?

Tags: spss, measurement

I am new to SPSS, and am trying to use SPSS to generate a variable on the quality of health service available to the residents of an area. Below are the categorical variables that could tell me the quality of health available to them.

- no insurance covering health care cost
- no access to ambulance service
- poor attention by medical personnel
- poor medical equipment
- poor drug provision
- time taken from dwelling to health centre more than 30mins
- poor waiting time at health facility
- health facility not available within neighbourhood

How can I generate a number value on the quality of health of this population from the number values of these variables, bearing in mind that several respondents may affirm each variable as true.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the use of SPSS only. Please review advice on software-related questions in the Help Center.

Comment: I've voted to leave the question open as there is a statistical question here. Are you interested in measures of health service for *individuals* or are you interested in aggregating your survey up to make measures of health service *in areas*?

Comment: I guess I should change my close vote to "unclear what you're asking" on a second reading. There are so many ways to get summary variables out of several that a good answer would be too long.

Comment: I do not have to use spss.I am interested in aggregating my survey up to make measures of health service in areas but at loss on how to achieve this. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to get on, this is my first time working with data

Comment: There is a large literature on quality of healthcare measures. Do you want to pioneer a new approach? If so, what do you not like about the way others do it?

Answer (score 2):

Are all of these variables 1 or 0 (true/false)? You could add them together. Are some more important than others? You could weight some higher and some lower, then add them.

Another idea is to look at principal component analysis (PCA). SPSS has a function for Categorical Principal Components Analysis. This will give you the combination of your variables that gives the greatest variation. It will also take weights.

Comment: Thanks Ben. It is a huge data which provides the percentages of respondents who answer true or false to questions on healthcare services. I am dealing with 57 areas and 8 variables as highlighted at the begining of the discussion

Comment: I think that if I find the mean of each of the variables in the 57 areas and add them together,  I can actually come up with a figure to equate the quality of health in an area. If for example I find the average number of respondents who have no health insurance, then decide that areas below average be represented by 2 and those less than average be represented by 1.

Comment: I can then add up the number representation of condition present in an area to give me a figure on the quality of health. What I would like to know is if there is any analytical function in spss or some other software which gives me  something near this